# Is there a way to keep widget always in centre in pyqt QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I want to know if it is possible to keep a widget always centred inside a QHBoxLayout.

For Example:
I want to make wid1 centred that it won't change its position at all

```
......wid1......
......wid1..wid2
wid2..wid1......
wid2..wid1..wid3
```

Comment: Based on your "example" above, you may prefer to use QGridLayout. For other situations, please add more details, as what you're asking is quite vague and may have different answers depending on multiple aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add more information to your question

if you want to center align a label you can use this line:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Edit:

you are using QHbox which aligns them horizontaly what you want to use is one that aligns them vertically like QVBoxLayout or in a grid like QGridLayout then use the alignment form my previous answer to align it center

```
hbox.addWidget(Widget, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

but even if you have other widgets aligned center it would then move a bit to the right or left

Comment: I meant to make it centred in a QHBoxLayout even if other widgets are there

Comment: No. This will center the *text* of the label, not the alignment of the widget.